# how datagridview cell color change on gridview cell click

Tags: c#

> when user click on gridview cell color will be change automatically
>   if not click so don't change color of gridview
>   How To Fix this and by Default 0 set on gridview cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This Is For Default Cell Value Set On Gridview Cell

```
   private void dataGridView1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Row.Cells["ship_qty"].Value = (decimal)0;
        e.Row.Cells["packs"].Value = (decimal)1;
    }
```

> This Is For Color Change

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
        }
```

> Hope This is helpful for you thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
        }
        else
        {

            CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = CellStyle;
        }
    }
```